# Can all non-quantum physical systems be efficiently simulated on a classical computer?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, simulation, physics

Is it true that simulating classical physical systems is in P, i.e. can be done efficiently on Turing machines or are there known exceptions? I'm thinking of chaotic systems but I'm also curious more generally whether there are theorems or counterexamples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Roughly speaking, I expect the answer will be yes, this can be done efficiently, but the longer answer is that I believe it takes some care to define what you mean by simulating.

First, we must define what we mean by "classical physics".  I will assume you mean (deterministic) Newtonian physics.

Second, we must define what we mean by "simulate".  This is trickier than it seems, as we have to define it as an algorithmic problem.  Thus, we must identify what is the input to the algorithm, and what is the desired output.  A plausible first try is that the input is the state of the system at some point in time (e.g., the location and velocity of all objects), and a duration of time, and the desired output is the new state after that duration passes.  However, this formulation is not solvable on a computer, because in Newtonian physics, the location of each object is a continuous real number, which cannot be represented in any finite amount of space.  As a result, neither the input nor the output can be represented in finite space, so it can't be solved by any standard algorithm.

A natural way to address this is to specify the location of all objects up to a particular precision, in both the input and the output.  But now this is not solvable.  Knowing the original location of an object to within $\pm \epsilon$ is not enough to know its location after some time passes to within $\pm \epsilon$, because tiny changes in the original location can lead to large changes in its final location.  An easy way to see this is to imagine throwing a ball aiming right at the edge of a wall.  If the ball hits the wall, then it will bounce back at you.  If your aim is slightly off and it misses the wall, then it will continue far past the wall.  So, tiny perturbations in the input state can cause an arbitrarily large change in the output state.  This means that no algorithm -- no matter how long it takes -- can accurately predict the output state, because the problem is simply information-theoretically impossible.

Perhaps this can be addressed (e.g., by giving an input state $x$, specified up to some precision $\pm \epsilon$, and asking for one possible output state that is consistent with some input state $x'$ that differs from $x$ by at most $\epsilon$), but I am not sure.

Also, you will need to ensure that the duration is specified in unary (i.e., we can build an algorithm whose running time is polynomial in the duration we want to simulate, but not one whose running time is polynomial in the log of the duration).

Finally, such a problem will not be in P, because it is not a decision problem.  I do expect it can be solved in polynomial time.  I don't know whether there is a precise way to formulate this problem so that there is a good definition of what it means to "simulate", but I anticipate it'll be solvable in polynomial time.

In particular, the extended Church-Turing thesis implies that yes, it is possible to simulate in polynomial time.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church%E2%80%93Turing_thesis#Variations.

A detail here is that many reasonable models of physics incorporate randomness (without necessarily using quantum physics).  It is not known that we can simulate such randomized systems in deterministic polynomial time, i.e., in P.  Instead, then, we normally indicate that they can be simulated in probabilistic polynomial time, i.e., with a polynomial-time algorithm that is allowed to use randomness.  The corresponding class of decision problems is then BPP, instead of P.  This may be largely a theoretical issue, as it is common to conjecture that P = BPP; but no proof of such a conjecture is known.

Answer (score 0):

As far as we know, space and time are continuous and exact physical simulations are impossible.

Approximate resolution by ODE's or PDE's are in indeed in P.